# Pegar conteúdo de uma div e salvar em uma matriz com expressões regulares(PHP)

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar o conteúdo da div com class="x-product" e salvar em uma matriz para que eu possa manipula-los depois.

Tentei esse código mas não funcionou.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.megamamute.com.br/hardware/placas-de-video?PS=16";

$conteudo=file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('/<div class="x-product">(.+)<\/div>/', $url, $conteudo);

//echo $conteudo[1][0];
echo $conteudo;
?>
```

Obs: Quero depois pegar a imagem, a descrição e o valor do produto para colocar em uma pagina do site que estou criando.

Comment: Não funcionou significa ele não pegou o padrão ou veio coisas a mais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ana tentar pegar o conteúdo de elementos HTML com expressões regulares é uma má ideia e no melhor dos casos só vai funcionar parcialmente pois HTML não é uma linguagem regular (que é o tipo que expressões regulares conseguem trabalhar com).

Sugiro que você use um parser HTML para o que deseja, uma boa opção é o [módulo DOM](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php), você pode ver [aqui](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html) uns exemplos legais de uso.

Comment: Obrigada! consegui com um código do manual que você sugeriu.